# Unexpected error when creating a create function with FastApi and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to create a function which creates a new post in my database
Here is my main.py file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from database import engine, get_db
import models
from models import *

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/posts', response_model=None)
def create_posts(post: Post,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    new_post = models.Post(titles=post.title, content=post.content, published=post.published)
    return {'data': new_post}
```

This is my models.py file:

```
from database import Base 
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default = "True", nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))
```

This is my database.py file

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker 

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost/fastapi'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Everything worked fine when i made a read function, there were no errors and everything worked fine, Now i am getting this error:

fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'models.Post'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/

I didnt put that response_model=None line first in the post() but later i decided to do so, but this fixed nothing and I got the same error

Comment: You'll have to configure your Pydantic model (i.e. what you're returning from the function) as being from an ORM (allowing attribute lookup). How you do this depends on whether you're using pydantic 1 or pydantic 2; you then set it as the `response_model` for the endpoint, allowing it to be documented properly and converted before being returned to the user.

Comment: can you please include some code if possible it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is not with `response_model=None`, but the type of argument that you are passing the `create_posts` function.

```py
@app.post('/posts', response_model=None)
def create_posts(post: Post,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

---

If you look at the hint section in the error:

**Hint:** check that <class 'models.Post'> is a valid Pydantic field type.

It's asking to check if `models.Post` is a Pydantic field type or not. But `Post` is not a Pydantic Model, it's a SQLAlchemy ORM model. So fastapi is not able to validate the response_body, that you are passing to the `create_posts` function.

---

There are two ways to solve this problem:

**1. Without Validation:**
You can remove the type for *post* argument inside the `create_posts` function. Like shown in the following snippet. This won't do any kind of validation on your *post* argument values.

```py
@app.post('/posts', response_model=None)
def create_posts(post,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

**2. With Validation:**

If you need validation then you have to create a pydantic model for your `Post`, then pass this model as a validation check to the `create_posts`

Create the pydantic model in `models.py` file:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime
class PostModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool
    created_at: datetime
```

Use the pydantic model from `models.py` inside of your `create_posts` function in `main.py` file:

```py
@app.post('/posts', response_model=None)
def create_posts(post: PostModel,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

---

**Note**: If you don't want to create two different models, one for ORM and other for pydantic, then have a look at [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/)

Comment: The error is caused by what's being returned, not by the input validation check - if it was the input check, a 422 error would be generated.

Comment: Yes, 422 error is generated when the validation check happens on the input check, but only when the type is pydantic model. If it isn't a pydantic model, then fastapi is not able to do the validation check, that's why the error is coming up. In this case the user is passing a SQLAlchemy ORM model, which isn't compatible with pydantic validation. So fastapi is asking to check the type of the input field

Comment: But how would the input to the endpoint be anything other than a pydantic model in this case? If it weren't, the error would be a 422 error. The error is caused by returning the ORM object directly, which FastAPI has no idea how to convert to an actual response - unless the response model is defined with allowing attribute lookup.

Comment: In the [fastapi documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#disable-response-model), they have mentioned that when we use `response_model=None`, it won't do any kind of validations on the returned response. So it doesn't matter what kind of object we are returning.

Comment: It does matter. You can't return any arbitrary object, as FastAPI doesn't have any idea how to convert that into an actual response. If you return a dict with only plain datatypes (str, int, float, etc.) it'll work - but you can't return any arbitrary object. In either case, you should try to aim to use a response model object (either as a return type hint or in the `response_model` argument) as that will actually validate and _document_ your endpoint response properly. You still have to return something that FastAPI _knows how to handle_ - which would be either a dict or a pydantic object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an arbitrary object without telling FastAPI something about the rules of how to convert/which fields to use from that object. You do this by defining a response model, which is a Pydantic model class. However, since you're returning an object (and not a dict-like object (for example an actual dictionary)), you'll have to tell Pydantic that you want to allow the object to be populated from its attributes:

```py
import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict


class PostCreateResponse(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool 
    created_at: datetime.datetime

    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    
    # in pydantic v1
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

You can then use this class as the response model for the controller endpoint, telling FastAPI that "this is what the response should look like, and what you should convert anything returned into".

```py
@app.post('/posts', response_model=PostCreateResponse)
def create_posts(post, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    new_post = models.Post(titles=post.title, content=post.content, published=post.published)
    db.add(new_post)

    # you might want to fetch the post instead before returning it
    # so that both the id and the timestamp field have actual values.
    # remember to call `db.commit` to persist the changes first.
    # 
    # You can also usually do this by refreshing the object in the
    # session after committing or flushing.

    return new_post
```